# div overlapping floating div - how to set this div starts under the floating one

Tags: css

I have few divs (1 div per row) and 1 of them has property `float: right`.
Now, the rest are overlapping this floating one. How can I set other divs to start under floating div?

Comment: can you share screenshot of ```output``` what you are getting and ```output``` what you want? also share you ```Code```.

Comment: do not use float. Check flexbox or css grid for layout purposes and you won't get into this kind of trouble.  ALso, if you want to receive a solution for your problem, please share your code that reproduces your problem and also what have you tried so solve it.

Comment: @MihaiT I didn't share the code because it was really simple problem with floating and I had no any styles to the rest of divs. Problem solved with ```clear``` property, but thanks for try!

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you expect people to put effort and spend their FREE time for FREE to help you, you can at least take the time to share the code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the CSS `clear: both;` property on the element that you want below the other floating elements.

More info about it can be found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float_clear.asp